# Twitter search (atom) API - exclude retweets

Tags: twitter, atom-feed, twitter-feed

I am using the Atom search API from Twitter. Now I present all (newest 5) tweets with a certain word. But unfortunately, many people retweet this one post and I get the same post 5 times.

Can I exclude retweets? If so, how?

Comment: I used now q=ConatiningWord -RT but is this reliable?

Comment: No, you might want to look in to regex.

Answer (score 17):

I've been successfully excluding retweets by adding **+exclude:retweets** at the end of my search query.

Comment: This seems to have the same effect as "-rt". I tried a few search strings containing **RT** and with **+exclude:retweets** they never return anything.

Answer (score 6):

I've done that and I'll share how you accomplish this. This would be your search query:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&rpp=100&q=[yourpost-value]-filter:retweets
```

This will exclude the retweets 100% and it worked for me :). If you have a problem with this, here is the alternate way:

Concatenate -filter:retweets within the function you are calling, here is an example:

```
if(isset($_POST['q'])){
  $q = $_POST['q']."-filter:retweets";
}
```

Now you just need to execute you search query:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&rpp=100&q=[post-value]
```

I hope this helps, have fun with programming :)