# Get TEXT only tweets using Twitter4j ? tweet that do not contain any media

Tags: java, twitter, processing, twitter4j, tweets

There are a lot of forums asking to get medias from twitter but how to do the opposite? I want to get only the tweets which do not contain any image/video/url. If found those tweets just skip and search for the next because I want to display a full text without "http://t..." thing at the end. I put this in ...

```
    cb.setIncludeEntitiesEnabled(false);
```

but, was not sure I did it right. Also, I write this code in Processing library but in Eclipse so I guess if you can show me the way in Java I will be fine, but a complete example please. I am very new to Java.

However, I have seen some people say about "filter=image" in tweet method but, I could not figure it out where to put this in. I have tried and fail.

Any suggestion? --Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use twitter Widget

Comment: I do not know how to do that

Comment: https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. Please try to be more specific. Saying "I could not figure it out where to put this in" doesn't really tell us anything. Where exactly did you try to put it? What exactly happened when you tried that? Can you please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

That being said, the best thing you can do is Google something like "twitter4j filter out images" or "twitter4j exclude images". More info:

- [Get Tweets with Pictures using twitter search api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920851/get-tweets-with-pictures-using-twitter-search-api): Notice the second reply mentions the approach of getting all tweets and then manually checking whether it has an image. You could do the same thing to check that a tweet does not contain an image.
- [How to exclude retweets from my search query results Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975866/how-to-exclude-retweets-from-my-search-query-results-options): This mentions an `exclude` filter and a `-filter` that might be helpful.

Please try something and post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post if you get stuck. Good luck.