# Does Watson Personality Insights use retweets?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Does Personality Insights use retweets when using a Twitter feed as input? And if so, is there a way to exclude them?

Comment: Are you asking about the "IBM Insights for Twitter" service instead?

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand the way that the Watson Personality Insights service works. The way the API is structured, the end user passes in content for Watson to analyze. That content can be anything from a collection of tweets, to a chapter of a book, to any long-form body of writing. The only requirement is that the number of words is greater than 100 and the total size is less than 20 MB.

Looping back to your question, the Personality Insights API will use whatever content you pass it, so it will only analyze retweets if it is given them. For more info on the API, check out the [REST API documentation](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/apis/#!/personality-insights/profile).

Comment: This SO question provides info on filtering out retweets using the twitter API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748880/exclude-retweets-in-twitter-search-api-1-1